# Is it possible to use flask template to show products in a grid / table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Trying to get product info (product name, product image, product price) to display in a grid using Flask template. There are 10 products, I was trying to show 5 products x 2 rows.

I was trying to get the product info to display like the image from this reference: 
https://schier.co/blog/2014/12/05/html-templating-output-a-grid-in-a-single-loop.html

But whenever I use < div > nothing shows up, so I'm back to using tables.

```
<table style="height: 200px;" width="200">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        {% for x in result %}
            <td style="width: 190px;">
                <a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" target=_blank><img src = {{ x['product_image'] }}></a>
                <a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" " target=_blank>{{ x['product_name'] }}</a><br>
                <a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" " target=_blank>{{ x['TLC'] }}</a>
                <br>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried other answers from SO, but the items either show up in one row or in one column, and couldn't get it to show up in a grid.

Edited:
Here is what I was hoping to get:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 1 name</p>
<p>product 1 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 2 name</p>
<p>product 2 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 3 name</p>
<p>product 3 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 4 name</p>
<p>product 4 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 5 name</p>
<p>product 5 price</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 6 name</p>
<p>product 6 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 7 name</p>
<p>product 7 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 8 name</p>
<p>product 8 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 9 name</p>
<p>product 9 price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p><img src="http://example.com/some_image_file.jpg" /></p>
<p>product 10 name</p>
<p>product 10 price</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Edited:
The app.py has these lines:

```
result = list_matching(keyword)
return render_template('product_list_template.html', result=result)
```

The "result" variable is a dictionary of lists of product information imported from another function which parsed the info from source.

```
[{'product_id': 'IP4D8', 'product_name': ... etc. ... 'price': '12.03'}, 
{'product_id': 'IP4D10', 'product_name': ... etc. ... 'price': '12.03'}]
```

Comment: Please write a minimal example for a static html table.

Comment: @strippenzieher - Thanks! I've added an example of what I was trying to get at. Will this need a loop? sorry, a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your whole for loop is inside `<tr>` tag which leads to show everything in one row.
The problem is with your html code.
Put those `<tr>` tags inside for loop.

```
<table style="height: 200px;" width="200">
    <tbody>
        {% for x in result %}
         <tr> {## Here ##}
            <td style="width: 190px;"><a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" target=_blank><img src ="{{ x['product_image'] }}"></a></td>
                <td><a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" target=_blank>{{ x['product_name'] }}</a><br></td>
                <td><a href="/get_asin/{{ x['asin'] }}" target=_blank>{{ x['TLC'] }}</a><br></td>
         </tr> {## And Here ##}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have edited the answer as per your comment.

Edit: I ran the following code and that displays everything in a table well formatted try running it once (you may have some bug in app.py of index.html file as that generally happens):
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

result = [{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb'}]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", result=result)

app.run()
```

templates/index.html:

```
<table style="height: 200px;" width="200">
<tbody>
        {% for x in result %}
        <tr> {## Here ##}
                <td style="width: 190px;">{{ x["a"] }}<br></td>
                <td>{{ x["b"] }}<br></td>
        </tr> {## And Here ##}
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Source of generated HTML:

```
<table style="height: 200px;" width="200">
<tbody>

    <tr> 
        <td style="width: 190px;">a<br></td>
        <td>b<br></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr> 
        <td style="width: 190px;">aa<br></td>
        <td>bb<br></td>
    </tr> 

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it before, it shows all the information in one column.

Comment: Use `<td>` element for seperating items in columns. First see about HTML tables (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). `<td>` is for cells all your items are in one `<td>` element that's why you see everything in one column first have a look at html table template.

Comment: Yes, I've referenced W3, but I still couldn't get it to display as a grid. I'm thinking a nested loop is needed? How to get it to loop to the next row?

Comment: Can you add your `app.py ` file also or which contains code to render this template.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I've post the relevant codes, didn't want to cram the whole page with code.

Comment: I have added some code try running that if problem is still not solved.

Comment: I've added your result to simulate 10 products, but it shows as 2 columns x 10 rows, with each product / row.
Is it possible to get 5 columns x 2 rows, with each product / cell?

Comment: You can change formatting of table the way you want.

Comment: No, it could not. Thats why I posted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I have to write in as answer. But it depends what you getting in result. If you are using flask-sqlalchemy, then you must be getting model object. So if you have "Product" models, so your result would be Product model with all the columns.
You can access those as:

```
{% for product in result %}
<p>{{ product.productname }}</p>
<img src='{{ product.imagename}}'> //ofcourse you have to give complete path before
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the data was parsed from an api source and collected into a dictionary of lists - I've just added some updates above.